# “404” and “There was no Home CMS page configured or found” after database backup/ import

Tags: database, magento

After importing a copy of the database, I got a 404 page on any page- the index, admin, etc. After some research, I read that core_store and core_website tables can sometimes get altered if the export / import settings are not not correct. After I updated the tables (as suggested [here](http://www.vectorns.com/blog/34-magento-notice-undefined-index-0-in-configphp-on-line-88-)), The site not semi-loads, but shows a \"There was no Home CMS page configured or found.\” message on the index, and 404 on the admin.

The site: http://dev.steamsaunadepot.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated. Really stuck here.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' rows in core_config_data table? If no, read second post in [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/27272/) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. The backup restore works, however, must be on a cleared database, and not overwrite.